# What is the correct way to encode HTML in JAVASCRIPT + JSON and decode it in PYTHON?

Tags: python, json, encoding, decoding

I have a JAVASCRIPT array allPois which contains several pois objects with the structure below:

```
    var poi = {
        title:  pois[x].title,
        lat:    pois[x].position.lat(),
        lng:    pois[x].position.lng(),
        html:   pois[x].html
    };
```

This is the JAVASCRIPT function that calls my server:

```
function save(){

    var jsonizedData = JSON.stringify({theArray:allPois});

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:       'POST',
        url:        'http://localhost:8000/save',
        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:   'json',
        data:       mydata,
        async:      true
    });
}
```

This is function on the server side that process the request:

```
def save(request):
   for object in request.POST:
      my_data = simplejson.loads(object)

   return none
```

What is the best way to encode/decode the parameter 'html' (that contains actually html code) so that it can be loaded properly in the server?

Comment: Please show the code which assigns a value to `pois[x].html`, specifically which jQuery function are you using?

Comment: pois[x].html is populated with the value of a textarea which is used to create/edit html - no JQuery function used here: pois[x].html = myTextArea.value;

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of the property `.html` is `string`, you don't need to do anything. JSON can handle string values all right. Any modifications by you will only make things worse.

Your problem is probably how you get the value from the text area. [See this jsfiddle how special characters are handled](http://jsfiddle.net/jtngP/2/).

But in modern browsers, no encoding/decoding is necessary at any step.

Oh, and make sure you clean the HTML to avoid [XSS and other attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: When the property .html contains actually HMTL code the function simplejson.loads(object) fails, i.e:  <QueryDict: {u'{"theArray":[{"title":"POI A","lat":40.4007793,"lng":-111.11104740000002,"html":"St<img src': [u'\\"http://sadas.com\\">art"},{"title":"POI B","lat":40.5507793,"
lng":-110.89104739999999,"html":"End"}]}']}>  makes simplejson.loads to fail:  Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 80 (char 80)

Comment: It looks to me I should encode the HTML before using JSON.stringify in my javascript code.

Comment: No. You just need to get the HTML in the correct way. `St<img src': [u'\\"sadas.com\\">art"` isn't HTML. It's just random text which looks similar to HTML but what is `src':[u'` supposed to mean? It should be `<img src="sadas.com">`. Where does that string come from? It looks like you created that with Python instead of typing it into the text area.